# How to automatically select a graphical quality level?

Tags: rendering, performance, settings

I'm making a game that lets the users choose their graphical settings, with the usual categories: low, medium, high.

I want to implement an "auto" category, and decide what the appropriate values are on startup. But I'm not sure how to do that.

For example in OpenGL, you could check the OpenGL version or query the memory through extensions (if provided) to guess at it, but that seems fickle since it may be the case that a low end graphics card has a high OpenGL version but bad hardware. Checking memory might be a bit better, but I assume it still is not the most accurate way of checking things.

A more robust approach would be to render in the background and check the FPS, but that could require setting up a whole scene, rendering it, etc. Most games seem to do this very quickly, so I don't know how they could set up a whole scene and do a bunch of quick tests.

Is there a fast way to do this?